# ContentDisallowed error about pickle when trying to enforce JSON serializer in Celery

Tags: json, serialization, flask, celery, pickle

I have the following in my **tasks.py** to specify that **json** should be used as the default serializer for Celery.

```
celery = Celery('app', broker = 'redis://localhost:6379/4')
from kombu import serialization
serialization.registry._decoders.pop("application/x-python-serialize")

celery.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND  = 'redis://localhost:6379/4',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT  = ['json'],
)
```

Also, while calling a task I specify the json serializer as:

```
r = t1.apply_async(kwargs = {'msg': msg}, serializer = 'json')
r = t1.wait()
```

But I still get the following error at the line calling `t1.wait()` with the traceback starting at that line.

> **ContentDisallowed: Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type pickle (application/x-python-serialize)**

The task **t1** raises different kind of exceptions, but I do handle them and try to return a value which is decipherable.

I am using Celery `3.1.17` (Cipater) and Flask `0.10.1`

So what exactly would be causing that error ? Let me know if any more info is needed.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use `json`, You need to specify

```
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Looks like you are missing

```
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly! But why doesn't specifying ``serializer = 'json'`` in the ``apply_async`` call achieve the same thing ?

Comment: may be that argument will be used to serialize task but not result?  http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.0-archived/userguide/executing.html#serializers

Comment: Even with all these settings, I still get the content disallowed error.